# Sonata model display

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, symfony-2.8

I have 2 entities, job and invoice. Invoice can have many jobs. Job can have one invoice. So far so good.

When it comes to creating the invoice on the create screen i ask them which company only, this is because i don't want to give them a huge number of jobs and only ones related to the company in question. I then save and send them through to the edit screen where i set the company to read only and do a query to get any invoiceable jobs. However using sonata type model only really gives a select or tick boxes. I'd like to almost show a list view where for each job i can show amount, job number etc, with a check box where i can then associate that job with the invoice

How can i do this and is there a better way of doing this than how i am now?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sonata_type_model_list`.

`$formMapper->add('jobs', 'sonata_type_model_list', [])`;

It is not mentionned in the documentation but you can see examples of it in use here: http://demo.sonata-project.org/

Comment: sonata_type_model_list only allows one selection so using it in the JobAdmin would work in order to find one invoice to link it to, but i'm trying to create an invoice and list a number of jobs that I want to associate with that invoice. So sonata_type_model_list won't work in this instance. I need something similar but allows you to select multiple and pass them all back as one. Im starting to think of creating a new sonata_type_model or just creating a new template.

Comment: Yeah ModelListType doesn't have a multiple option

Comment: Is there any other way of doing this?